# Generating function for canonical transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, chain-rule, hamilton-equations, canonical-transformation

I've been reading through some notes on integrable systems/Hamiltonian dynamics, and got stuck on a problem relating to generating functions and canonical transformations.

Firstly, some background.

> A coordinate change $(\vec{q},\vec{p})\to (\vec{Q},\vec{P})$ is called canonical if it leaves Hamilton's equations invariant, i.e. the equations in the original coordinates
>   $$\dot{\vec{q}}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial\vec{p}},\quad \dot{\vec{p}}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial\vec{q}}$$
>   are equivalent to
>   $$\dot{\vec{Q}}=\frac{\partial\tilde{H}}{\partial\vec{P}}, \quad \dot{\vec{P}}=-\frac{\partial\tilde{H}}{\partial\vec{Q}}$$
>   where $\tilde{H}(\vec{Q},\vec{P})=H(\vec{q},\vec{p})$.

The notes also include the following proposition, but I don't know if it is intended to be used here.

> A map $\vec{x}\to\vec{y}(\vec{x})$ is canonical iff $D\vec{y}$ is symplectic, i.e.
>   $$D\vec{y}J(D\vec{y})^T=J$$
>   where $J$ is the symplectic matrix.

Generating function method for finding canonical transformations:

> Suppose we have a function $S:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}.$ Write its arguments $S(\vec{q},\vec{P})$. Now set
>   $$\vec{p}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \vec{q}}, \quad \vec{Q}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \vec{P}}.$$
>   The first equation lets us to solve for $\vec{P}$ in terms of $\vec{q},\vec{p}$. The second equation lets us solve for $\vec{Q}$ in terms of $\vec{q},\vec{P}$, and hence in terms of $\vec{q},\vec{p}$. The new coordinates $\vec{Q}$, $\vec{P}$ we find this way will give a canonical transformation. Checking this is just a careful application of the chain rule.

My Problem:

So I decided to try and work out this 'careful application of the chain rule', i.e. prove that the transformation obtained via this generating function method is canonical. I have been unable to do so, and help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

****my attempt****

Try to prove $\dot{\vec{P}}=-\frac{\partial\tilde{H}}{\partial\vec{Q}}$.
Thinking of $H$ as $H(\vec{q}(\vec{Q},\vec{P}),\vec{p}(\vec{Q},\vec{P}))$, and using the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial\tilde{H}}{\partial Q_i}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_j}\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_j}\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial Q_i}$$
which equals, using original Hamilton equations
$$=-\dot{p}_j\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i}+\dot{q}_j\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial Q_i}$$
Meanwhile, 
$$-\dot{P}_i=-\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial q_j}\dot{q}_j-\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial p_j}\dot{p}_j,$$
so we want 
$$\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial p_j}=\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i},\quad
\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial q_j}=-\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial Q_i}.$$
Not sure how to go about showing this using $S$.

Comment: Write the definition of canonical transformations in components.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Also note - I have edited the post as it was unclear before. To clarify, the problem I am trying to solve is to show that the new Q,P coordinates obtained via the generating function method involving S does give a canonical transformation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It's an exercise in the commutativity of partial derivatives. I've posted a new answer explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

You've restated the canonical transformation with two equations in matrices. It will help to invert them, viz. $\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial P_i}=\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_j},\,\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial P_i}=-\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_j}$. Let's derive this from $p_j=\frac{\partial S}{\partial q_j},\,Q_i=\frac{\partial S}{\partial P_i}$ viz.$$\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial P_i}=\frac{\partial^2S}{\partial P_i\partial q_j}=\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_j},\,-\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_j}=-\frac{\partial^2S}{\partial p_j\partial P_i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial P_i}\left(p_k\frac{\partial q_k}{\partial p_j}\right)=\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial P_i}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the response - but I'm not convinced yet. W.r.t. your first result, I also was able to show $\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial P_i}=\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_j}$. As far as I know however, this doesn't imply $\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial p_j}=\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i}$ which is what we needed. Is it legal to 'invert' partial derivatives like you have done? (Because in general $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\neq \frac{1}{\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}}$)

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on in your second result. It seems to be a tautology?

Comment: @MerkZockerborg It's legal by the chain rule$$\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial b_j}\frac{\partial b_j}{\partial a_k}=\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial a_k}=\delta_i^k.$$I've fixed a typo in my last calculation.